# Is there a way to read a image file path in an excel column and convert this file path into a picture in html?

Tags: html, vba

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a excel sheet whithin one of the columns has several file paths adressing different pictures stored in the same folder as the excel file. What I would like to do  is read each file path and show each picture in a table on my html file. However, all my attempts failed and the only thing I got is a string that shows the filepath.

Is there any hint of a way to do it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: To convert filepath to image, use `<img src="filepath" >`

Comment: Thanks, but in VBA this "filepath" need to assume the filepath writen in the excel file, as value. But I still got a error when I write` .writeline "<TD> " &"<img src=" ThisWorkbook("Sheet1")" />" &"</TD>"`

Comment: Please add your current codes to the question and tell me check again. I guess that sheet1 is not a corect target. What about rows and cells?